# Neuronal Network just won't train correctly

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I want to create a Neuronal Network capable of guessing numbers from the MINST database. I'm using a library from npmjs.org (npm install --save mnist)

I just can't get my neuronalnetwork to learn the numbers and I also tried it with a basic xor problem, still doesn't work.. Doesn anyone see why?

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
import * as mnist from 'mnist';

const ACTIVATION = "sigmoid"

const input = tf.input({
  shape: [784],
});

const denseLayer1 = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 30,
  activation: ACTIVATION
});

const denseLayer2 = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 30,
  activation: ACTIVATION
});

const output = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 10,
  activation: ACTIVATION
});

const model = tf.model({
  inputs: input,
  outputs: output.apply(denseLayer2.apply(denseLayer1.apply(input)))
});

model.compile({
  optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.1),
  loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError
});


let coolSet = mnist.set(100, 300);
let inputs = [];
let outputs = [];
coolSet.training.forEach((oneTraining, index) => {
  inputs.push(oneTraining.input);
  outputs.push(oneTraining.output)
});
outputs = tf.tensor2d(outputs);
inputs = tf.tensor2d(inputs);

let testInputs = [];
let testOutputs = [];
coolSet.test.forEach(oneTest => {
  testInputs.push(oneTest.input);
  testOutputs.push(oneTest.output)
});

train().then(() => {
  testInputs.forEach((x, index) => {
    const predictedOutput = model.predict(tf.tensor2d([x]));
    console.log(`Excpected Output: ${testOutputs[index]}
  Output: ${predictedOutput.toString()}`)
  });
});

async function train() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const config = {
      shuffle: true,
      epochs: 10
    };
    const response = await model.fit(inputs, outputs, config);
    console.log(response.history.loss[0]);
  }
}
```

I can't get the NeuronalNetwork to learn.. The loss lowers itself.

Outputs:

```
Excpected Output: 0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
  Output: Tensor
     [[0.0957722, 0.1015996, 0.0940665, 0.0999646, 0.1097334, 0.0965195, 0.1045253, 0.0923973, 0.1008056, 0.1046157],]

15ms 150us/step - loss=0.0889 
Epoch 10 / 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to note for this neural network.

The problem to solved is a classification problem. It means that given an input, the output is a selection of a category among the different labels. The output is a probability ( range from 0 - 1). The sum of the output should sum to 1. Generally, in classification problems, the last layer is a `softmax` activation, which takes a input layer and output a score indicating the probability for each possible category.

As for the loss, the best option is either the `binaryCrossentropy` or the `categoricalCrossEntropy`. One does not really compute the euclidian distance between the predicted and the expected output. It has less meaning here opposed to when it is a regression problem.

```js
const ACTIVATION = "sigmoid"

const input = tf.input({
  shape: [784],
});

const denseLayer1 = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 30,
  activation: ACTIVATION
});

const denseLayer2 = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 30,
  activation: ACTIVATION
});

const output = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 10,
  activation: 'softmax'
});

const model = tf.model({
  inputs: input,
  outputs: output.apply(denseLayer2.apply(denseLayer1.apply(input)))
});

model.compile({
  optimizer: 'adam',
  loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy'
});


let coolSet = mnist.set(100, 300);
let inputs = [];
let outputs = [];
coolSet.training.forEach((oneTraining, index) => {
  inputs.push(oneTraining.input);
  outputs.push(oneTraining.output)
});
outputs = tf.tensor(outputs);
inputs = tf.tensor(inputs, [100, 784]);

let testInputs = [];
let testOutputs = [];
coolSet.test.forEach(oneTest => {
  testInputs.push(oneTest.input);
  testOutputs.push(oneTest.output)
});

train().then(() => {
  testInputs.slice(0, 10).forEach((x, index) => {
    const predictedOutput = model.predict(tf.tensor([x]));
    console.log(`Excpected Output: ${testOutputs[index]}
  Output: ${predictedOutput.equal(predictedOutput.max(1)).toString()}`)
  });
});

async function train() {
    const config = {
      shuffle: true,
      epochs: 1000, 
      callbacks: {
        onEpochEnd: async (_, l) => {console.log(l.loss)}
      }
    };
    const response = await model.fit(inputs, outputs, config);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mnist/1.1.0/mnist.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My answer worked too, but I'm a newbie to neuronal networks so I gues your's is correc too! Also: Do you know where to learn what Functions to use for what? :)

Comment: I gave some pointers on how to build layers for a generic classification problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was rather easy: just train it more! I thought that 10 epochs and 100 iterations are enough, but I tried it with 1000 know and now it works!